# How to change image in expandable listview for each parent?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I'm trying to change the image for each parent in expandable listview. but im not getting what to do.

I've already added the image in the parent by using drawable left but now for each parent i need to change images.

Comment: post your code plz!

Comment: try this library  https://github.com/Android-Tutorials-Hub/expandable-list-view-tutorial

Comment: A little code will help for sure!

Comment: Issue solved by adding image in the adapter. thanks for the reply everyone